# The maximal real algebraic field

Tags: extension-field, real-numbers, algebraic-numbers

I want to know what is the maximal real subfield of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. Namely, what is

$$\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\cap\mathbb{R}?$$

For a moment i thought that this was the field of totally real algebraic numbers, but then i realized is a strict contention only (e.g., $\sqrt[3]{2}$)

Comment: I don't expect any characterization other than $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\cap\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25734/is-there-a-purely-algebraic-criterion-which-characterizes-the-real-algebraic-num.

Comment: @lhf Great reference.

Answer (score 0):

It's the set of real numbers which are roots of a non-zero polynomial with rational coefficients.

Comment: Isn't this just a rephrasing of the definition?

Comment: @lhf Yes. I'd like to know what the OP thinks about it, though

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and yes that is a rephrasing of the definition? I am now thinking that there is no characterization of that intersection...